# incompatible types java.lang.charSquence found int

Tags: java, android, arrays

I am new to android and was trying to create some tabbed activity added to my navigation drawer.
so i get around it very well with strings just fine.
problem comes when i now want to add icons to my tabbs instead of strings.
I replace my array of strings with one of icons but then i get incompatibilty error.

i know am supposed to some how convert these icons from int to string but i really cant figure out how.

also tried finding different ways to achieve icons but they all involve me deleting almost my entire code. i need help.

here is my java class

```
package com.example.alvin.feedyourbaby;


/**
  * Created by alvin on 7/29/17.
 */

public class dataFragment extends Fragment {
View view;
ViewPager viewPager;
TabLayout tabLayout;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup   container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.sample, container, false);
    viewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    viewPager.setAdapter(new sliderAdapter(getChildFragmentManager()));
    tabLayout = (TabLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.sliding_tabs);
    tabLayout.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        }
    });

    return view;
}
private class sliderAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter{


    final  int  tabs[]={R.drawable.ic_child_care_black_24dp    ,R.drawable.ic_menu_black_24dp, R.drawable.ic_add_black_24dp};


    public sliderAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }


    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return new contentFragment();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }
    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return tabs[position];
    }
}`
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this inside **oncreate()**:

```
int  tabs[]={R.drawable.ic_child_care_black_24dp    ,R.drawable.ic_menu_black_24dp, R.drawable.ic_add_black_24dp};

        for (int i=0;i<tabLayout.getTabCount();i++){
            tabLayout.getTabAt(i).setIcon(tabs[i]);
        }
```

So your code be like:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup   container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.sample, container, false);
    viewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    viewPager.setAdapter(new sliderAdapter(getChildFragmentManager()));
    tabLayout = (TabLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.sliding_tabs);
    tabLayout.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        }
    });

    int  tabs[]={R.drawable.ic_child_care_black_24dp    ,R.drawable.ic_menu_black_24dp, R.drawable.ic_add_black_24dp};

            for (int i=0;i<tabLayout.getTabCount();i++){
                tabLayout.getTabAt(i).setIcon(tabs[i]);
            }


    return view;
}
```

Comment: i dont see how this is going to help me cause at the end i still cannot parse the drawables to the getpageTitle()

Comment: Do this way and not in the getpage title. You said that you want to change the string title to an icon, so I have the same issue that you have and this resolve my problem, remove code from getpage title and try do this if Works has you exepected just fine. :) @alvinMemphis

Answer (score 0):

`tabs[position]` returns an `int` and `getPageTitle` needs an `String` you need to set it manually :

```
@Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        String title = ""
        switch(position):
            case R.drawable.ic_child_care_black_24dp:
                title = "title 1";
                break;
            //code
        return title;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a string array which stores the title of each tab like this.

```
private class sliderAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter{
private String[] pageTitle = {'Child Care', 'Menu', 'Add'};
//-----your rest of code here--------------
@Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return pageTitle[position];
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

this is invalid

```
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    return tabs[position];
}
```

because tabs is an `int[]` so you are breaking the contract about what the method should return.

since the method is returning a CharSequence you can too return ANY class that implement that interface. like CharBuffer, Segment, String, StringBuffer or StringBuilder, String is the most likely to be : )

something like:

```
return String.valueOf(tabs[position]);
```

---

btw: inspecting your code will spot this:

```
 int  tabs[]={R.drawable.ic_child_care_black_24dp....
```

so converting those ids from drawables into a string makes not much sense since that is not bringing much usable info to the user.... please update the qustion and tell us what are yoyu trying to achieve!

Comment: am trying to get my tabs to show drawables instead of strings

Answer (score -1):

The type of `tabs[position]` is `int`, but `getPageTitle(int position)` should return a CharSequence Object. Try to replace your return statement with `Integer.toString(tabs[position]);`